# Pin widget to screen with ViewFlipper as background

Tags: android

I'm having some trouble with a layout in Android.Currently I have a layout with a ViewFlipper that allows me to change the background image  and a couple of buttons at the bottom of the screen (inside my flipper).

Is there any way of keeping my widgest pinned to that exact part of the screen while I swipe between images ?

Comment: If you want the `Buttons` to not move with the images than don't put them in the `ViewFlipper`. You don't have other solutions.